# "...words had been too many..."

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage

Example:

> His **words had been too many** to fit into a notecard.

(I'm using *had been* instead of *were* because it's a past-tense narrative. And the person is already dead.)

What puzzles me is that the phrase *words had been too many* has [no results](http://words%20had%20been%20too%20many) on Google. Zero.

Why is this? Is there a grammatical mistake? Or people just tend to use *were* even in the past tense, even if the person is no longer alive?

**EDIT:**

Same with [thoughts](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22thoughts%20had%20been%20too%20many%22&oq=%22thoughts%20had%20been%20too%20many%22&gs_l=serp.3...65605.65850.0.66012.4.4.0.0.0.1.100.198.1j1.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..4.0.0._ZgC2o6Xnk8):

> His **thoughts had been too many** to fit into a notecard.

Comment: `words were too many `is still applicable.

Comment: Both are correct. The tense could be anything depending upon the context.

Comment: Think of the construction as implying an implicit/deleted element - *[**the quantity/number of**] his words were too many*. If you find fault with the usage, I suggest *your [objections are too many*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22objections+are+too+many%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Your usage of ***had been*** rather than simple ***were*** is credible, but will probably come across as excessively verbose in most contexts. Don't get over-enthusiastic about using Past Perfect just because you *can*.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, one cannot depend upon 'Google' to find all answers as it's primarily a Search Engine.

Tense doesn't matter, as it varies depending upon the context. Both are correct.